# Getting errors when plotting using ggpairs

Tags: r, ggally

I have the following df:

```
> str(merged)
'data.frame':   714 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ Date       : Date, format: "2013-03-29" "2013-03-29" "2013-03-29" "2013-03-29" ...
 $ patch      : Factor w/ 7 levels "BVG1","BVG11",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 ...
 $ prod       : num  2.93 2.77 2.86 2.87 3.01 ...
 $ workmix_pct: int  100 10 16 13 17 21 22 100 11 19 ...
 $ jobcounts  : int  9480 968 1551 1267 1625 1946 2123 7328 810 1374 ...
 $ travel     : num  30.7 34.3 33.8 29.1 28.1 24.9 34 31.8 32.7 36.4 ...

> head(merged)
        Date patch     prod workmix_pct jobcounts travel
1 2013-03-29  BVG1 2.932208         100      9480   30.7
2 2013-03-29 BVG11 2.769156          10       968   34.3
3 2013-03-29 BVG12 2.857344          16      1551   33.8
4 2013-03-29 BVG13 2.870111          13      1267   29.1
5 2013-03-29 BVG14 3.011260          17      1625   28.1
6 2013-03-29 BVG15 3.236246          21      1946   24.9
```

I simply want to plot pair wise plots and correlations.

I am getting an error:

```
> ggpairs(data=merged, colour=merged$patch)
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
Error in Math.difftime(235.666666666667, base = 10) : 
  'log' not defined for "difftime" objects
```

second time, I tried without the date and I could draw the pairs but still get some errors:

```
> ggpairs(data=merged_cpy, colour=merged_cpy$patch)
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
```

Any idea what it is and how to resolve these?

Comment: Those are not errors, merely messages/warnings. You can pass the `binwidth` parameter to `stat_bin` with `ggpairs(..., params = c(binwidth = 0.1))`

Comment: could you give an example... How would it look like? sorry new to all this... I did `ggpairs(data=merged, coloumns=c("prod","travel","job_counts"),colour=merged$patch, stat_bin=0.1)` but not working and error is the same `stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
Error in Math.difftime(235.666666666667, base = 10) : 
  'log' not defined for "difftime" objects`

Comment: You didn't use the right syntax. You need to specify that the object you are passing to the `ggpairs` function is for the parameter `params`. The `stat_bin=0.1` is then passed to `stat_bin`. I'm guessing `stat_bin` uses `log` to determine some graphical parameters. You need to convert your `difftime` column to a numeric class.