# Binwidth error while using ggpairs

Tags: r, ggally

I am trying to generate a plot from my data set that gives the correlation between my variables.

I am using the library GGally. 
here is my one line code.

```
ggpairs(Imputed_data,  title = "Scatterplot Matrix for the features of data Set")
```

I am getting a error

> _bin()`using`bins = 30`. Pick better value with`binwidth`.

My data set has 14 variables, 13 are numeric and 1 is a factor variables.

I could understand that there is a problem with declaration of bins, that I should mention (bins=10) 
But, I am struck how I should do it in my code. I am new to R programming.

Comment: Please share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)

Comment: please check the answer and accept if relevant

Answer (score 1):

I have dataframe of 33 variables
I got a similar question

Following things helped me

[Getting errors when plotting using ggpairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103190/getting-errors-when-plotting-using-ggpairs)

Here it is explained how, to configure ggpair we have to pass binwidth parameter to stat_bin() using params .

In my case i followed another explanation on
https://github.com/ggobi/ggally/issues/184

Following code worked for me

```
ggpairs(t, aes(colour = V33, alpha = 0.2), lower=list(combo=wrap("facethist",  
binwidth=0.5)))
```

here i am coloring using a factor variable V33
alpha is 0.2 and binwidth 0.5

I did not find anywhere what binwidth does exactly.
But in my understanding it should be something regarding size.